# React: Array not rendering in correct order after first time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

The first time my array is rendered it is in the correct order, however, if it is changed the rendered order remains the same.

For example:

```
construct() {

    this.state = {
        test_array: [1,2,3,4]
    }

    let self = this;

    setTimeout(function(){
        self.scramble();
    }, 5000);
}


scramble() {
    this.state.test_array = [3,1,2,4];
    this.setState(self.state);
}

render() {

    this.state.test_array.forEach(function(item){
       console.log(item);
    });

    return (
        <div>

            {this.state.test_array}

        </div>
    );
}
```

Results in:

```
On the console (the current order, correct):
    3
    1
    2
    4

Rendered as DOM (the original order, incorrect):
    1
    2
    3
    4
```

Any idea why this is failing to render in the correct order?

Comment: Ok - lesson learned: Don't ignore the key warning in console: "Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop." See: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You were very close. Here's a few things I changed to fix it:

1. `construct` should be `constructor`
2. You always need to call `super()` as the first line of a constructor. (You don't really need to worry about this, it's an Object Oriented thing; google it if you're curious)
3. Use "arrow functions" instead of "keyword functions" or `.bind(this)` to prevent `this` from changing contexts
4. Do not modify `this.state`; always call `this.setState` if you want it to change

```js
class OrderThing extends React.Component {
  constructor()  {
    super()

    this.state = {
      test_array: [1,2,3,4]
    }

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.scramble();
    }, 5000);
  }


  scramble() {
    this.setState({
      test_array: [3,1,2,4]
    });
  }

  render() {
    this.state.test_array.forEach(function(item){
      console.log(item);
    });

    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.test_array}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const div = document.createElement('div')
document.body.appendChild(div)
ReactDOM.render(<OrderThing />, div)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

A few suggestions here.

**First of all**, there is no `construct()` in js, but there is **`constructor()`**.

**Secondly**, you should always call super method with props as an argument in constructor, like this:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    ...
}
```

**Finally**, react developers highly recommend to modify state only using `setState()` method.
So you should rewrite your scramble method.

```
scramble() {
    this.setState({test_array: [3,1,2,4]});
}
```

This changes should help you a little bit.